# Make a Class Schedule Report

Tags: crystal-reports-8.5

How can I make my Crystal Report look like the attached image? I have had no success creating it with a crosstab.

[image]

Comment: How are you populating the class information? Are you manually entering your classes or pulling it from a table automatically?

Comment: im pulling it from a query

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that Crystal Reports isn't really equipped to handle the format you're dealing with. And here's why:

Let's assume for a moment you've already figured out how to interpret your query into something usable. Since we aren't using a Cross Table, the best you could hope for would be setting a Details section for each individual time slot and arranging a large number of formulas into a grid shape:

[image]

The problem is that every Formula would need to be unique; interpreting whether there is a Class at that Time and Date, and which Class it is. There would be up to **168** of those formulas and you'd have to *manually go in and modify each one* to check for their own unique combination of Date and Time. Which defeats the whole purpose of using a computer - to make repeated tasks *easier.*

Plus you'll have difficulty with the formatting: You'd need to program every "cell" to use a unique set of colors based on the displayed Class. That part is technically doable, but there's no way to "merge the cells" when classes last longer than a half hour. You'd end up with something like this:

[image]

So don't torture yourself trying to make this happen in Crystal. Even with all the time and effort it would take to formulate the grid, there's no good way to make it look like your screenshot.

That said, it looks as though you managed to put a schedule together in Excel. Is there any reason you can't use Excel instead? It's a much more powerful tool, and a cursory Google search suggests it can handle queries as well.